# Compile/Build Issue with Img Relative Paths

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, web-compiler

I am building a site using Visual Studio and WebCompiler is enabled.
When I compile on build my path files are changing to:
    `../../img/icons-@2x.png`

rather than what the expected outcome is:
    `../img/icons-@2x.png`

This is my current compilerconfig.json file:

```
[ 
   {
    "outputFile": "dist/css/style.css",
    "inputFile": "styles/style.scss",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "relativeUrls": false
   }
]
```

I've racked my brains/googled for hours but cannot figure out what is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Just to note I resolved this issue by including the following in my compilerconfig.json:

```
"options": {
  "sourceMap": false,
  "relativeUrls": false
}
```